# How to Parse the Fancy Text From Text Area

Tags: javascript, html, regex, fonts, html-parsing

I am facing some issues when copy paste the fancy texts and emojis in a textarea,

Like  and

I have removed the emojis with following code:

```
e.content.replace(/([\u2700-\u27BF]|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\u2011-\u26FF]|\uD83E[\uDD10-\uDDFF])/g, '')
```

Also wanted to remove the special fonts and fancy texts as well, but not finding a way.

is there any way around for this, like i did for the emojis.

Comment: Try `.replace(/[\u{1F170}-\u{1F189}]+/gu, '')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - When I run OP's code it appears to already remove "Fancy Text" using `\uD83C[\uDC00-\uDFFF]`  Can you explain why that works and if it is better use `[\u{1F170}-\u{1F189}]` as in your example?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this worked, but for some the fancy text like copying it from MS Word Art is converting the text to special characters.

Comment: @shoaibMunir Don't you think copying texts is out of scope here? If copy/paste is acting up, it is an issue with your app/OS settings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, I mean, before trying the fix you suggested exact the same text from MS Word was showing in Textarea, but now after the fix it converts into special characters like "%&$#" in case of other fancy text this fix is working fine. anyway to omit those special characters as well?

Comment: If you need to also remove speical chars, use `.replace(/[\u{1F170}-\u{1F189}\p{P}\p{S}]+/gu, '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECMAScript 6 regex solution to match the squared letters is

```js
.replace(/[\u{1F170}-\u{1F189}]+/gu, '')
```

To also match math and punctuation symbols, you can use the following ECMAScript 2018+ compliant regex:

```js
.replace(/[\u{1F170}-\u{1F189}\p{P}\p{S}]+/gu, '')
```

The `u` flag is required to make `\u{XXXX}` notation and `\p{X}` Unicode categories work.

*Pattern details*

- `\u{1F170}-\u{1F189}` - squared letters
- `\p{P}` - punctuation proper
- `\p{S}` - math symbols.